# Create and link new Google document in one step

Tags: google-docs

I'm trying to use Google Docs to organize some information.  To do this, I need to create a bunch of documents and have a link to each document in another document.  This level of organization is actually more than one level deep, e.g. a document of master links, each of which goes to a document with more links to the actual documents.

For this to be efficient I need some way to create a new document and put a link to that document in the current document.  Right now I have to switch to a Drive window, then click twice on New, and then Google Docs.  Then after the new document comes up and I have entered the title into the document I copying it to the clipboard.  Then I have to go back to the original document, hit Ctrl+K, then paste the title into the "Link" field.  Originally this would immediately find the new document and populate the Text field with the title when I selected it.  But after doing this a few times it inexplicably stopping finding my new documents, requiring me to paste the text into the Text field, then go back to the new document window and copy the URL, then past it into the Link field.

How can I create a link to a new document more directly, without having to go through all these steps?  Something like a keystroke to initiate the process, followed by typing the title, and then enter to complete would be minimal.  If I have to create a script (.gs) or something to accomplish that is ok, although obviously if I waste too much time trying to figure how to implement this it would cut into my time savings.